# Poisson probability for x greater than

Tags: probability

When we calculate poisson probabilities for say $x> 4$, we usually find out by summing up probabilities of  $x=0$, $x=1$, $x=2$, $x=3$ and $x =4$ and subtracting the aggregate from 1. But sometimes, I find that probabilities of $x=5$, $x=6$..etc are added up till $x$ of $p$ values equal zero.

I am confused about when to use $1-p(\ldots)$ and when to add up $p$ of  values greater than  $x$

hope my question is clear. I am copying both ways of doing so that it will be clearer

1. for $\lambda=  10;\,  P(X\geq5) = 1-P(X \leq 4)= 1-(0.0005+0.0023+0.0076+0.0189) =0.9707$
2. $\lambda= 2;\,  P(X \geq6) = 0.0120+0.0034+0.0009+0.0002=0.0165$

which of the above methods is followed? does it depend on $x> \lambda$?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, it's a matter of convenience: if you need to calculate $P(X \geq 4)$ it is much easier to find $1-P(X<3)$, but if you want $P(X> 453)$ there's no point of doing it the latte way.

Comment: In that case, the answer we get should be the same? Tried both methods but answer varies. Still couldn't get a hang of it. Looking at a number of solved problems I found a pattern 


When we have to find p of x greater than (x>6 for example) when x is greater than lambda (for ex,lambda is 4), adding up p values of x=7,x=8,x=9 and so on till p value is 0 in the table is done. 

If x < lambda (for ex, to find out p of x>3 when lambda is 6), formula used is 1-p(x=0 + x=1 + x=2 + x=3)  

But is this the principle used?